# Обновление виджета из другого активити

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Как сделать, чтобы виджет обновлял выводимую информацию при закрытии другого активити? Делаю блокнот. При добавлении виджета на экран он показывает информацию, которая хранится в активити Edit, но при редактировании блокнота, информация в активити меняется, а в виджете остается старая.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на виджет открывается Edit, но при изменении текста и сохранении, виджет не обновляется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, который я использовал

```
static void updateWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
    SharedPreferences sp, int widgetID) {
        // Редактирование заметки при нажатии на виджет
        Intent editIntent = new Intent(context, Edit.class);
        editIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        editIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID);
        editIntent.putExtra(com.bezruk.note.DataBase.KEY_ROWID, noteID);
        PendingIntent eIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,widgetID,editIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Обновление виджет
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetID, widgetView);
        widgetView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.text_widget, eIntent);
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы при нажатии кнопки Save информация на виджете обновлялась на новую

Перепробовал уже много всего, но не получилось этого сделать.

Подскажите, как сделать, добрые программисты.

Comment: Слабо понятно чего вы хотите добиться. Вы из активити А открываете В, какой-то текст там вбиваете и хотите его увидеть в А при возврате из В?

Comment: Отредактировал первое сообщение

Comment: С виджетами не работал... На вскидку варианты - может помочь пользование `onActivityResult` или пользование `LocalBroadcastManager`. А вообще, бегло пробежав глазами доки на тему можно найти ответы на все вопросы: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: Там, вроде, даже отдельный раздел, посвящённый созданию активити для редактирования содержимого виджета.

Comment: Мне кажется, вам нужно посмотреть пример из доки, конкретно вот этот [обработчик кнопки](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r1/com/example/android/apis/appwidget/ExampleAppWidgetConfigure.java#84), и вызываемый им [метод](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r1/com/example/android/apis/appwidget/ExampleAppWidgetProvider.java#ExampleAppWidgetProvider.updateAppWidget%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.appwidget.AppWidgetManager%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете `AppWidgetProvider`, можете обновлять виджет из активити таким способом:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
// используйте массив и EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS вместо AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
// т.к., похоже, onUpdate() вызывается только в этом случае:
int[] ids = {widgetId};
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

<sup>([Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7738687/1429387))</sup>